# What does the /t parameter mean in the shutdown command?

Tags: windows

Using this, the computer takes a few seconds to start the shutdown process.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call (["shutdown", '/s'])
```

Whereas, using this, the shutdown starts immediately.

```
import os
os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
```

I'd like to know why this happens and what the /t parameter means.

Comment: Those are different commands?

Comment: I just cannot understand this question...

Comment: I've edited your title to reflect the question you _should_ be asking.

Comment: Can you clarify whether there's a difference when you make an *equivalent* call -- ie. subprocess.call (['shutdown', '/s', '/t', '1']) ?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I think "*Nix" is your edit? Given as `/t` (vs `-t`) makes this unambiguously a Windows command vs a UNIX-family command, could you explain how it's appropriate here?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy honest mistake :-)

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation? Or the online help? If topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the parameters of the `os.system` call. Notice the `/t 1` parameter that specifies a time interval.  It means "wait one second before shutting down".

Notice that the subprocess.call command is missing this parameter. Without the `/t` parameter, the default is 30 seconds before initiating shutdown.

Type `shutdown /?` at the command prompt for more details.